# Why do I need to refresh a JSP page after inserting data into database?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

I'm working with Spring/Hibernate using `SimpleFormController`. Everything is working just fine. I'm retrieving data let's say for the sake of simplicity from the `Country` database table.

The code for retrieving those data in `showForm()` method in my `Controller` class is as follows.

```
@Override
protected ModelAndView showForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, BindException errors) throws Exception
{
    ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView();
    try
    {
        session=NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<model.Country>list=session.createQuery("from model.Country order by countryId").list();
        mv.addObject("list", list);
        session.flush();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        mv.addObject("msg", e.toString());
        mv.addObject("status", "-1");
    }
    return mv;
}
```

I need to perform Insert, Update and Delete (and some other) operations only on one JSP page and they are being done successfully but when I insert a row into my Oracle database by clicking the `Add` button, the data held by the database table are shown on the JSP page only when the page is **refreshed**.

In other words, as soon as I press the `Add` button (after entering necessary data in the text fields), corresponding row in the database is created successfully but the HTML table on the JSP page that should be populated becomes empty as shown in the following snap shot.

[image]

The data in the HTML table are displayed only when I reload the JSP page as shown in the following snap shot.

[image]

What I need is to populate the HTML table as soon as I press the `Add` button on my JSP page. There shouldn't be need to refresh the page to display data in the HTML table from database.

Is there a way where I need not refresh the page to populate the HTML table from the database?

Comment: That's quite simple. You're not retrieving data from the database on the `POST` method (the `onSubmit()` method of `SimpleFormController`).